# Is there is a significant association between (whole) milk consumption and cancer

Tags: cancer, milk

I consume high quantities of whole milk (probably a third-gallon a day), and I'm concerned with the potentially negative cancer-causing effects of this consumption.

I found the following claims on this [website](http://www.tcolincampbell.org/courses-resources/article/milk-and-prostate-cancer-the-evidence-mounts/?tx_ttnews):

> Researchers are looking, not only at whether milk increases cancer
>   risk, but how. The answer, apparently, is in the way milk affects a
>   man's hormones. Dairy products boost the amount of insulin-like growth
>   factor (IGF-I) in the blood. In turn, IGF-I promotes cancer cell
>   growth.3-5 A small amount is normally in the bloodstream, but several
>   recent studies have linked increased IGF-I levels to prostate cancer
>   and possibly to breast cancer as well.
>
> Milk does other mischief. Its load of calcium depletes the body's
>   vitamin D, which, in turn, may add to cancer risk. Most dairy products
>   are also high in fat, which affects the activity of sex hormones that
>   play a major role in cancer.

What does the research suggest is the case?